# CSS font-style animation refuses to work in Safari and Firefox

Tags: css, animation, safari, css-animations

I am working on a very simple animation in which I have a font go from normal to oblique over a short period of time. It works well in Chrome but Safari and Firefox are not cooperating. Searched far and wide on the internet for an answer and nothing has worked! I have included webkit prefixes, and even tried separating the attributes by name, duration, etc.

I am using an older and newer version of Safari on two separate computers. First is Safari 6.2 on a Macbook Pro from 2012 (OS X 10.8.5). Second is Safari 9 running on a 27" iMac (El Capitan).

Like I said, it works in Chrome (both on the old and new computer), but I can't seem to figure the other browsers out. I even tried changing the font to Times and having the animation go from normal to italic… Still nothing.

Please help me out! This is killing me.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="body">
<span id="first">One</span>, <span id="second">Two</span>.</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.body {
  font-family: "Arial Rounded MT Bold";
  font-size: 9em;
  line-height: 1em;
  letter-spacing: -3px;
  font-kerning: normal;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shear {
    0% {font-style: normal;}
    100% {font-style: oblique;}
}

@-moz-keyframes shear {
    0% {font-style: normal;}
    100% {font-style: oblique;}
}

@-o-keyframes shear {
    0% {font-style: normal;}
    100% {font-style: oblique;}
}

@keyframes shear {
    0% {font-style: normal;}
    100% {font-style: oblique;}
}

#first {
  -webkit-animation: shear 6s 1;
  -moz-animation: shear 6s 1;
  -o-animation: shear 6s 1;
  animation: shear 6s 1;
}

#second {
  -webkit-animation: shear 9s 2;
  -moz-animation: shear 9s 2;
  -o-animation: shear 9s 2;
  animation: shear 9s 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`font-style` is technically `not animatable`. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-style

The fact that it works in some browsers is just plain lucky. You can try faking it with `transform: skewX(-10deg)` and adjust the angle to what suits you.

Here's an example http://codepen.io/t3hpwninat0r/pen/jqZEWd

Click on "View compiled" in the css box to see it with vendor prefixes

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling font-style was the issue. Gonna work with transform from now on. Thanks so much!

Comment: This answer is outdated now. `font-style` animates in Chrome/Firefox/Safari now, and binary (untweenable) properties like this are indeed animatable. The MDN link in the answer notes "Animation type: discrete" for this and other binary properties.

Comment: It's only taken 6 years, but yes. Now that it has animation type discrete, `font-style` can be set in keyframes but it still doesn't interpolate. If you want smooth animation you would need to use `transform`.